# When does a airflow dag definition get evaluated?

Tags: airflow

Suppose I have an airflow dag file that creates a graph like so...

```py
def get_current_info(filename)
    current_info = {}
    <fill in info in current_info relevant for today's date for given file>
    return current_info

files = [
    get_current_info("file_001"),
    get_current_info("file_002"),
    ....
]

for f in files:
    <some BashOperator bo1 using f's current info dict>
    <some BashOperator bo2 using f's current info dict>
    ....

    bo1 >> bo2
    ....
```

Since these values in the current_info dict that is used to define the dag changes periodically (here, daily), I would like to know by what process / schedule the dag definition gets updated. (I print the current_info values each run and values appear to be updating, but curious as to how and when exactly this happens).

When does a airflow dag definition get evaluated? referenced anywhere in the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DAGs are evaluated in every run of the scheduler.

[This article](https://medium.com/@ishan4488/apache-airflow-scheduler-code-586c264f192) describes how the scheduler works and at what stage the DAG files are picked up for evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

After some discussion on the [airflow email list][1], it turns out that **airflow builds the dag for each task when it is run (so each tasks includes the overhead of building the dag again (which in my case was very significant))**.

See more details on this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59995882/8236733